# Permission usert Tomcat7 for send files to apache2 folder (httpdocs)

Tags: php, permissions, apache2, tomcat7, plesk

***UPDATE 28/07/2016***
Help me please.
My problem is I have a ubuntu server with the following configuration

[image]

In summary ::
 my internal server (tomcat 7) .war owner user does not have permission to create, modify, ... folders, upload files (but yes, to read all this).
my module in plesk is apache (is not whether it would be better, CGI, or FAST-CGI).
I've tried everything, changed owners folders permissions for adding groups, more users, I modified mod_jk, I changed server.conf, worker.properties, tomcat.users, catalina.policy, ........
And I can not get the user and owner (tomcat7) .war, achieve create, modify, delete folders, upload files etc ...
However from the local tomcat, which makes the request when the user is www-data, you can do all.

can someone please help me with some idea?Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I finally had to switch to a windows server because of problems with plesk and ubuntu.

and voila, everything working properly